# Using if statements to check for multiple values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I'm having some trouble with this

```
$AuthUserIDs = array('299816740352593','1783393008638862');

foreach($AuthUserIDs as $AuthUserID){
  if($userID == $AuthUserID){
   //DO SOMETHING
   }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what to say in the if statement to check for multiple IDs from the array.

Comment: Just read the docs for an example of how to use foreach sanely. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the for loop, just use [`in_array`](https://secure.php.net/in_array).

```
if (in_array($userID, $AuthUserIDs) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm actually trying to shorten,

if($FBuserID == '299816740352593' || $FBuserID == '1783393008638862'){//DO SOMETHING}

I want to input the authorized id's into the if statement, but I don't want to have to keep multiplying it.. I just want to be able to input it into the array, so I need to be able to say something like FOREACH authUserID place it into this if statement...

I'm using the above if statement to filter through a whole list of user IDs

Comment: That's exactly what the above does. In your example in the comment, but the user IDs into an array and then use `in_array` as above.